# Problema con Gorilla Player

Tags: xamarin, visual

tengo un problema a la hora de instalar gorilla player en visual studio. En el proyecto de android y de ios, mediante el administrador de paquetes nuget he instalado UXDrivers.GorillaPlayer.SDK.AutoConfig la única versión que hay que es preliminar, pero cuando voy al emulador en genymotion me sale la página de gorilla para conectarme y me salen dos, una dirección ip que es la de mi equipo y otra dirección ip que es la del virtualbox, con ambas me da error, y me dice "XAML: Number of parameters specified does not match the expeted number." ¿Alquien sabría de que podría tratarse? Muchas gracias

Comment: He conseguido solucionarlo, he instalado los tres componentes de Gorilla player y ha funcionado.

Comment: Que version de Gorilla PLayer usar en mi terminal movil para trabajar con xamarin Form en tiempo real en VS2017